# Is it possible to set multiple list elements using slice notation without inserting new elements?

Tags: python, slice

I'm trying to set several elements in a list with slice notation. For example, I'd like to set the 2nd and 3rd elements of `a` to `100` and `200`, respectively:

```
a[1:2] = [100, 200]
```

but that is setting the 2nd element to `100` and inserting `200` instead of replacing the 3rd element. Is this even possible in Python (using Python 2.7 if that matters)? I could easily iterate, but I wanted a more elegant Pythonic solution (even if it might be considered less readable).

```
>>> a=[0]*4
>>> a
[0, 0, 0, 0]
>>> a[1:2] = [100,200]
>>> a
[0, 100, 200, 0, 0]
>>>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You meant to do `a[1:3]`, not `a[1:2]`. Note the [rules on Python slice indexing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/509295/712603): the slice `[start:end]` goes from `start` to `end-1`.

```
a=[0]*4
a[1:3] = [100,200]
a
# [0, 100, 200, 0]
```

Comment: Precisely. user748113, you should accept this as the correct answer.

Comment: Thanks! Can't believe I missed that :)